# Baby shower games

Tags: party

This question is more of a wiki about what games would be fun to play at a baby shower. My wife is throwing one and the games are fairly boring. I was hoping I could help think of at least one, original, fun game for her and her friends. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you have enough people, [Werewolf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mafia_(party_game)) (a.k.a. Mafia or Assassin) makes a great party game - it often reveals exactly what your friends think you are capable of!

The 'turns' are fairly quick, so it works well with large groups (in the dozens) - although you might want to limit the length of discussion/argument in between!

It also has the added advantage of not needing any equipment and as a by-stander to the party you'd make the perfect 'Narrator' (they moderate the game, rather than participating).

From the wikipedia page:

> A party game modeling a battle between
>   an informed minority and an uninformed
>   majority. Players are secretly
>   assigned roles: either "mafia", who
>   know each other; or "townspeople", who
>   know only the number of mafia amongst
>   them. In the game's "night" phase the
>   mafia covertly 'murder' a townsperson.
>   During the day phase, all of the
>   surviving players debate the
>   identities of the mafia and vote to
>   eliminate a suspect. Play continues
>   until all of the mafia have been
>   eliminated, or until the mafia
>   outnumber the townspeople. A typical
>   game starts with seven townspeople and
>   three mafioso.

**EDIT**: The thread '[Anyone know more 'social' games like 'Werewolves](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/637/anyone-know-more-social-games-like-werewolves)"' has a great list of similar 'party games'.

Answer (score 2):

So, this is not really a board or card game, but I think it could be fun for you to do.

At one of my friend's baby showers, they played this game where they removed the labels on a few jars of baby food. Then, each guest (that wanted to play) had a taste from each jar. The goal was to try and correctly guess the type of baby food in each jar. And, they gave the winners - the top 2 or 3 people with the most correct answers - some prizes.

Like I said, not a BCG, but could definitely be fun, and memorable...

Answer (score 1):

How about [Pictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pictionary)? I've played it with quite large teams (about 10 on each side) and it's a riot.

Answer (score 0):

There's a great book called [Super Party Games](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0806959150) that describes a bunch of games that can be played by groups of 10 or more. I generated a set of puzzles for one of the games described in the book. Each player is given a sheet of paper that they tie to their forehead where they can't see it. On each sheet of paper are three letters, and you have to arrange yourselves to spell out a secret quote without telling anybody what letters are on their heads. You can [download the puzzles](http://code.google.com/p/donkirkby/wiki/FortunePuzzles) and print out one of the puzzles for your group size. If you don't mind being excluded from the game, you could find a quote related to babies and make your own puzzle for the people at the party to play.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm hosting a large party I also find it's useful to have several different fast 4-15 player games out, so that people can circulate in and out of game-playing and casual conversation.
With that in mind: I'd start with Apples to Apples.

Answer (score 0):

There's a wonderful free party game called a number of names, including [Eat P**p You Cat](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/30618/eat-poop-you-cat) which is best described as the love child of Pictionary and the telephone game.

The game is hilarious and requires only pencils and paper for each participant. It requires no skill and can be explained in two minutes.

Comment: P**p? I'm pretty sure we wouldn't be offended by the un-censored version ;)

Comment: @Jon Hadley - Yes, but I was actually poking fun at [this discussion](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/68/5) on meta.

Answer (score 0):

Baby Bingo - create bingo cards with baby-related words, randomly arranged.  (It's best to use a reasonably small set of 25-50 words; include specific words related to the mother or baby if possible.)  Write a story that includes all of the words.  Read it slowly and let people mark off the words on their cards.  First person to get 5 in a row wins.

Answer (score 0):

[Apples to Apples](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/74/apples-to-apples) is a really great game for moderately large groups. In my experience ladies tend to enjoy it. [Scattergories](http://scattergories.net/) is also fun, and scalable by dividing into teams. Lastly, my family and I recently discovered [Guesstures](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2379/guesstures), and the best antics by far were those of my 80-year-old grandmother, on which fact my 14-year-old niece and I agree (read: good for all ages).